What does "doing checks" mean here?
Serving large parties
My restaurant requires us to ask how they’re "doing checks" at the beginning because we can’t do splits without a manager. Once I find out how checks are, I ring in a water and modify it with a description of the person (red hair; flannel shirt; sports hat). If it looks like they’re all dresses similarly I’ll just straight up ask for their first name and do it that way. Plus it allows for a way to connect with the customer.

How will you handle (doing) the issue of a single group check or separate checks (splits)?

I can't make any sense of this question.

writing up the charges

"doing checks" refers to how the party wants to be billed at the end of the meal. Traditionally there would be a single check, and the patrons would work out among themselves how to apportion the payments ("I got the hamburger, I owe $20..."). But often the patrons will request that the waiter create separate checks for each of them (or for groups of patrons), to simplify that process -- the patrons don't have to calculate their individual sales taxes themselves, it will be done by the computer that creates the checks.
